# Chess Table Spacing - HTML,CSS , JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I wanna build a chess table with buttons,
here is the code that I have created the table :

```js
document.write('<h1>Welcome to Lucky Table game</h1><table>');
var cell_id = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  document.write('<tr>');
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j += 2) {
    cell_id = i * 8 + j + 1;
    document.write('<td><input type="button" class="black" onclick="playTheGame(\'a' + cell_id + '\')" id ="a' + cell_id + '" /></td > ');
    cell_id++;
    document.write('<td><input type="button" onclick="playTheGame(\'a' + cell_id + '\')" id="a' + cell_id + '"/></td>');
  }
  document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

```css
input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  column-gap: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /margin: 0;
  / border: none;
}

td,
tr {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}
```

I have tried so many option to remove this spacing between rows and I couldn't find a solution, thanks for your help.

[Board Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvTq2.jpg)

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested your code with Chrome and there are no spacings between rows

Comment: Tested on Firefox no space either. CSS comment code block should be `/* ... */` not `/ ... /`

Comment: I would recommend using an 8x8 `grid`-container instead of a `<table>`, which really hasn't been advisable in well over a decade. Also, you can make the containers themselves clickable, which would free you from not having to add buttons.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use the grid system to make a chessboard. Grid system gives you better control and specificity for various options.
An example could be this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- for the top row you add 8 div here -->
  
</div>
```

Right after this HTML declaration, you need to declare div following the number of the cells in the chessboard.
**for the class wrapper, add this CSS stylings**

```
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 0;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 70px);
 grid-template-rows: 40px repeat(8, 70px) 40px;
 grid-auto-flow: row;
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current code add `{border: none; border-radius: 0}` on the input, add border only to "td" and remove borders for "tr" and "table". Play around a bit with the border color.